# Get username from oAuth2 access token API Manager

Tags: wso2, mediator, wso2-esb

The use case occurs once user is authenticated and obtain an oAuth2 access token from Wso2 API Manager and we want to obtain username again from this access token.

To obtain access token I've followed normal steps published on: [API Manager] (http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Token+API#TokenAPI-GeneratingaccesstokenswithusercredentialspasswordgranttypeGenerating)

Does WSO2 AM provide any REST method to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes..  There would be two ways that you can obtain user name

1. APIM would return the user name with the Access token. Here user name would be embedded with the access token. You can find more details from [here](http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Saving+Access+Tokens+in+Separate+Tables)
2. You can obtain the user name and user's attribute during access token verification process. Once access token is verified successfully, It would return back with JWT token which contains user's attributes. Then you can extract use name from JWT.  You find more details on [here](http://docs.wso2.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=32350971). Basically inside the APIM, you can extract JWT token in transport header.   But,  if you want to retrieve the JWT token for the use of your application, you can send the access token to "OAuth2TokenValidationService" service and validate it and then it return back with JWT. (But "OAuth2TokenValidationService" is a web service.). You can use  web service client to invoke this service (such as SOAPUI)

Comment: It works with first solution. Just a small question related: Setting **EnableAssertions** true API Manager generates an encoded token which contains the username. This encoded token is easily decoded (by a small JAVA code).  But would be possible to automatize this decoding by a Mediation Sequence in AM? Should I programme a JAVA class Mediator Sequence and add it to AM? I've found information on [Mediators] (http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM150/Adding+a+Mediation+Extension#AddingaMediationExtension-APIExtension)